# How can Angular dual-listbox respond to a selection event?

Tags: angular, listbox

I am using Angular Dual-Listbox, and I want to add customized moving up/down button by the side. However, I cannot figure out what entries in the confirmed (right) box have been selected. In the html:

```
<dual-list [sort]="keep_sorted" [source]="source" [key]="key" [display]="display" [filter]="filter"               [(destination)]="confirmed" height="400px" [format]="format" [disabled]="disabled" (selected)="onSelected($event)">
</dual-list>
```

when items on the confirmed (right) box are selected, I want to know what they are. Obviously (selected) event is not supported, while (click) event is not returning any useful information. Any ideas?